# Need help writing numbers in the Reverse ORDER

Tags: java

I need some help with this assignment I've been given. Not asking anyone to do my work but I'm really honestly stuck on how to even do this.

I'm supposed to write a program that prompts the user to enter 10 numbers and then have it write all the numbers in reverse order.

Example: 
Enter 10 Numbers: 23 89 21 55 67 89 99 13 98 78
Reverse Order:    78 98 13 99 89 67 55 21 89 23

So far all I have is how to get the user inputs. If anyone can push me in the right direction, i'd be very grateful!

```
import java.util.*;

public class ReverseNumbers
{
public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] values;
    values = new int[10];

    //Ask the user to enter 10 integers
    System.out.println("Please enter 10 numbers:");
    for (int i = 0; i< values.length; i++) 
    {
      values[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    int[] reverseNums;
    reverseNums = new int[10];
    for (int i = (values.length -1); i>= 0; i--) 
    {
      reverseNums[ reverseNums.length -1 -i ] = values[ i ];
      System.out.println( reverseNums[ i ] );
    } 
 }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track, what's it doing wrong?

Comment: You're on the right track, but think: why do you need another array to store the reverse values in? Why not just loop over your `values` array in reverse, printing as you go?

Comment: Just comment out this line reverseNums[ reverseNums.length -1 -i ] = values[ i ]; and print values[i]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you dont want to store the reversed values

```
    for (int i = (values.length -1); i>= 0; i--) 
    {       
      System.out.println( values[ i ] );
    }
```

Comment: Its funny that I got an upvote when I gave the same content as a comment and then a downvote when I give it as an answer :P

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks good for reading inputs into `values`. Now you can loop over that array in reverse and print the values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
  System.out.println(values[values.length - i - 1]);
```

Think about it, when `i == 0` it will print `values[9]` since 10 - 0 - 1 = 9. At the end, when `i == 9` it will print `values[0]` since 10 - 9 - 1 = 0.

As you can see, there is no need for the extra `reverseNums` array.

PS: If you want, you can combine `int[] values;` and `values = new int[10];` into a single line: `int[] values = new int[10];`

Answer (score 0):

Read in the whole line as a string using `Scanner.nextLine()`, and then split it into an array using `String.split(" ");`.  After this, you can simply iterate from the end of the array going backwards and print the numbers.

Comment: That all sounds like it makes sense but I'm not quite sure how to loop the values or to split them and make it go backwards. This is only my first semester of programming.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not an assignment then why not try using http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/ library

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(int[] array)
```

Comment: "I need some help with this assignment I've been given."

Comment: Actually first thing he says is that it is an assignment.

Comment: but if the question is searched in google, most cases it wont because someone has an assignment. It's helpful for the most part to keep this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is creating the array correctly. You are just printing out the numbers in the original order because your second for-loop is iterating over them backwards. You can see the correct result by adding the statement below after the  last loop:

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(reverseNums));
```

You can also perform the complete task with only one iteration:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

int[] reverseNums= new int[10];
System.out.println("Please enter 10 numbers:");
for (int i = 0; i< values.length; i++) {
  reverseNums[values.length -1 - i] = keyboard.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(reverseNums));
```

Answer (score -1):

To reverse it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    reverseNums[values.length - i - 1] = values[i];
```

Comment: Op didn't want the reverse natural order of the numbers, but the reverse of the entry order. So 2,5,3 -> 3,5,2 (not 5,3,2)

Comment: @AdriaanKoster didnt notice that. Fixed. (Removed the call to `Arrays.sort()`